# wp_set_object_terms() return invalid_taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

i tried to set the taxonomy of  a post but it always return invalid_taxonomy error.

```
$categorys_ids = wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $categorys, 'categorie-video');
            error_log('categorys brut = ' . $data['category'] .'postid '.$post_id.'categorys = ' . json_encode($categorys_ids));

            //byme
            if (is_wp_error($categorys_ids)) {
                error_log('categorys =There was an error somewhere and the terms couldn\'t be set');
            } else {
                error_log('categorys =Success! The post\'s categories were set.');
            }
```

Comment: Does 'categorie-video' exist?

Comment: What does taxonomy_exists('categorie-video') return?  If it returns false, then my next question would be, have you called register_taxonomy()?

Comment: yes it return false.
thanks. i will search how to add a taxonomies.

Comment: i have used simple taxonomie word press plugin but the return value of taxonomy_exists('categorie-video')  always is false ,that's why i got  'invalid_taxonomy' error when updating or inserting  taxonomie via 'wp_set_object_terms()'